# How to test a node.js server from command line

Tags: node.js, curl

I am programming an iOS app that needs to use an web service to create an authentication token.  I have written a node.js server to create the token.

I know that I could use curl to test this server locally from the command line but I can't seem to get it to work.

here is a snippet of the server code

```
var app = express();
....

app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
   // create token
   ......

   res.json({
      identity_token: jws
   });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function(err) {
   if(err) throw err;        
   console.log('Express server running on localhost:%d', port);
});
```

I have tried using the following curl command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user_id":"USER_ID","nonce":"NONCE"}' http://localhost/authenticate
```

The error I receive is "Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused"

I would really appreciate any help or examples on how to test this server.

Comment: Which port is your node server running on?

Comment: Did you also try `http://localhost:3000/authenticate` in case it's using the default?

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't familiar with the syntax to specify the port.  However, now when I run the curl command I'm getting a blank line in response starting with '>'.   I was expecting to see the token string.